# SQL IF..ELSE Scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working through a problem and I am stuck. I have two tables:

```
S#  Sname StatusNum City
s1  Smith 20 London                   
s2  Jones 10 Paris                    
s3  Blake 30 Paris                    
s4  Clark 20 London                   
s5  Adams 30 Athens    


S#  P#  J#  QTY
s1  p1  j1  200
s1  p1  j4  700
s2  p3  j1  400
s2  p3  j2  200
s2  p3  j3  200
s2  p3  j4  500
s2  p3  j5  600
s2  p3  j6  400
s2  p3  j7  800
s2  p5  j2  100
s3  p3  j1  200
s3  p4  j2  500
s4  p6  j3  300
s4  p6  j7  300
s5  p1  j4  100
s5  p2  j2  200
s5  p2  j4  100
s5  p3  j4  200
s5  p4  j4  800
s5  p5  j4  400
s5  p5  j5  500
s5  p5  j7  100
s5  p6  j2  200
s5  p6  j4  500
```

I need to sum the qty from table 2 and list them, but also if the qty is over 1000 list the Sname from table 1.

What I have done currently is:

```
Select SUM(qty) as total_sales, S#
From SPJ
Group by S#;
```

Which gives:

```
total_sales S#
900         s1  
3200        s2  
700         s3  
600         s4  
3100        s5
```

This will give me the sums, but I am stuck on how to get the names with S2 and S5, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the first table to a derived table that consists of your aggregation query, and use a `case` expression to display the name when sales are greater than 1000:

```
select 
    t.S#
  , case 
      when s.total_sales >= 1000 
        then t.SName
      else ''
      end as SName 
  , s.total_sales 
from (
    Select SUM(qty) as total_sales, S#
    From SPJ
    Group by S#
    ) s
  inner join table1 t
    on s.S# = t.S#
```